# Is there a special name for the operands of a multiplication?

Tags: terminology

Sometimes operands for a specific operation are given a special name. For example, in division the first operand is a quotient, the second is a divisor. Is there a word that means "one of the operands in a scalar multiplication"?

(I'm trying to figure out a concise name for some variables in my code; the purpose of these variables is essentially to be multiplied.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've heard of the usage "multiplicand" $\times$ "multiplier" $=$ "product".

Answer (score 7):

You could also use the word "factor".

Answer (score 4):

I would use the word "multiplicand".